# How to store private key in Key Container?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I want to store a private key in a key container to create a signature over data for an asp.net website.

```
//First I Read PrivateKey from text file that i Uploaded with FileUpload(fuPrivateKey)
var pk = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fuPrivateKey.FileBytes);
CspParameters csp = new CspParameters();
csp.KeyContainerName = "PrivateKeyForSignature";
DSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new DSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);//error
rsa.FromXmlString(pk);
```

but I got the following error at line of `DSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new DSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);`:

> The specified cryptographic service provider (CSP) does not support this key algorithm.

I have used this method for storing an `RsaCryptoServiceProvider` key without any problem. However when I want to use it for DSA it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I take a look at the default (no argument) constructor of `CspParameters` then [I get this text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xw9ywed4(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This form of CspParameters initializes the [ProviderType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.providertype(v=vs.110).aspx) field to a value of **24**, which specifies the PROV_RSA_AES provider.  This default provider is compatible with the [Aes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx) algorithm.

If I look up the constructor that accepts a 32 bit integer [I get](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dh4wac4(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the `CspParameters` class with the specified provider type code.
>
> ...
>
> To specify a provider compatible with the [DSA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsa(v=vs.110).aspx) algorithm, pass a value of **13**to the *dwTypeIn* parameter.

So it seems to me this can be solved by calling the right constructor of `CspParameters` with the right code.

Answer (score 1):

The criteria as mentioned by @MaartenBodewes is correct. `CspParameters` by default are configured to RSA container. Which is why, there were no errors when the same was tried with `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

```
CspParameters csp = new CspParameters();
```

is same as:

```
CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1);
```

To use crypto service in `DSACryptoServiceProvider`, the parameterized constructor has to be called as:

```
CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(13);
```